# Google-Fit - How to read when recording client is subscribed to local device DataSource

Tags: android, google-fit

I am using Google Fit Android API for reading step count and distance covered from the user's current phone. For that I am subscribing to DataSource as below:

```
val dataSource = DataSource.Builder()
  .setDevice(Device.getLocalDevice(this))
  .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
  .setType(DataSource.TYPE_DERIVED)
  .build()

Fitness.getRecordingClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
    .subscribe(dataSource)
    .addOnSuccessListener {
        // access step data
    }
    .addOnFailureListener {
       // handle exception
    }
```

Since I want data only from the current phone, I use the above code. But when I start accessing data using `HistoryClient` it does not give any data.

Below is my code for accessing step data:

```
Fitness.getHistoryClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
      .readDailyTotalFromLocalDevice(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
      .addOnSuccessListener { displayData(it) }
      .addOnFailureListener { Log.d("MainActivity", "Step Count Reading Exception: $it") }
```

But if I use `DataType` instead of `DataSource` in the recording client subscription code it is recording data correctly.

Is my code for `DataSource` correct? Do I need to read history data differently for `DataSource`?

Comment: What are your error logs?